# scrapy items for dynamic fields

Tags: python, scrapy

the item field needs to change depending on which index the `start_urls` is set on

for example

```
    location = input("Location:")
    second_location = input("Second Location:")

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + location,
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + second_location

        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + third_location,
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + fourth_location
    ]

    if self.start_urls[0]:
       item['location'] = location

    if self.start_urls[1]:
       item['location'] = second_location
```

what happens is that `item['location']` will be fixed and will not change dynamically, making all of the items output location the value of location, despite if its `self.start_urls[1]`

This is what i have so far.

**items.py**

```
class Item(scrapy.Item):
    business_name = scrapy.Field()
    website = scrapy.Field()
    phonenumber = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()


    # third_location = scrapy.Field()
    # fourth_location = scrapy.Field()
    visit_id = scrapy.Field()
    visit_status = scrapy.Field()
```

**myspider.py**

```
search_item = input("Input The Search Item: ")
location = input("Location:")
second_location = input("Second_Location:")


# city = [
#     "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston", "Phoenix", "Philadelphia", "San Antonio", "Fort Worth", 
#     "San Diego", "Dallas", "San Jose", "Austin", "Columbus", "Indianapolis",  "Seattle", "St. Paul", "Nashville", 
#     "Louisville", "Plano"
# ]

# rancity = random.choice(city)


class YellowSpider(scrapy.Spider):


    name = "yellow"

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + location,
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + second_location
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + third_location,
        # "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" + search_item + "&geo_location_terms=" + fourth_location
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.seen_business_names = []
        self.seen_phonenumbers = []
        self.seen_websites = []
        self.seen_emails = []




def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('div.v-card a.business-name::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(href, self.businessprofile)

    for href in response.css('div.pagination a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

def businessprofile(self, response):
    for business in response.css('header#main-header'):
        item = Item()
        item['business_name'] = business.css('div.sales-info h1::text').extract()
        w = business.css('a.secondary-btn.website-link::attr(href)').extract()

        item['website'] = str(w).strip('[]')

        if self.start_urls[0]:
            item['location'] = location

        if self.start_urls[1]:
            item['location'] = second_location

        s = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()
        item['email'] = [item[7:] for item in s]

        item['phonenumber'] = business.css('p.phone::text').extract_first()
        for x in item['email']:
            #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names
            if x not in self.seen_emails:
                if item['email']:
                    if item['phonenumber']:
                        if item['website']:
                            self.seen_emails.append(x)
                            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no sense.

```
if self.start_urls[0]:
    item['location'] = location

if self.start_urls[1]:
    item['location'] = second_location
```

As long as the elements of `start_urls` are not empty strings (or other falsy values), both of these blocks will be executed.

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to make `item['location']` same as the location used in the starting url. The simplest way to do this would be to make your requests hold this information.

You should make custom requests in [start_requests()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests), and use the method described in https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments to pass the location as request meta data.

After that, just pass it along to any consequent requests.